# C API for spawning a FCGI server?

Tags: c, nginx, fastcgi

I made a FCGI program in C using fastcgi.com's API. I've called `FCGI_Accept` like the docs say. When I run the resulting executable it just runs through like a CGI program, and exits.

I need the API for web servers where it listens on a UNIX domain socket. I am using `nginx` which does not spawn FCGI programs on its own and fastcgi.com's API library. I do not want to use other servers or libraries to spawn my FCGI program.

Comment: A fastcgi program starts as any other program (ie. thru `main`). You need to configure your HTTP server to start it as a FastCGI application.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch nginx doesn't spawn FastCGI applications.

Comment: This means that `ngnix` might not support FastCGI, or else expects FastCGI applications to be started externally (e.g. by your system startup scripts e.g. in `/etc/init.d/`). Then it is still a sysadmin issue to start the FastCGI application, and the question don't belong here (since it is not related to coding).

Comment: Actually it's a programming issue because launching FCGI is not possible. nginx is a kind of proxy and FCGI's are usually launched by the webserver. They cannot be launched themself. I need to code a FastCGI server that listens for connections.

Comment: There is no requirement that the webserver has to start the fcgi binary. FWIW, the fcgi program might already be running, such as, for example, php-fpm which is generally launched through the regular distro init mechanisms.

Comment: @jørgensen True, but how does PHP do it? Simply calling `FCGI_Accept` is not sufficient. Which is all my code does, currently.

Comment: @unixman83: Find a small hello-world like example of FastCGI, compile it, and then make it work on your system. You'll learn how to configure and use it. You don't need something as complex as PHP, just a `hello-world-fastcgi.c` example. IIRC, the FastCGI library has such an example inside. (It could even just handle `GET` HTTP requests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem trying to launch a FastCGI application written using the fcgi_stdio library for use with nginx.  If I launch the application normally it acts like normal CGI and exits immediately.  I'm not sure what secret sauce is normally done to get the application to act like FastCGI instead of CGI by the http daemon (that nginx doesn't do), but [spawn-fcgi](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/spawn-fcgi) does it.  It's available in the EPEL repository for use with RHEL/CentOS/Amazon Linux/etc.  I don't know if that helps your situation, but it was what I finally ended up using.

Answer (score 3):

Just follow these steps -

1. Open the socket using FCGX_OpenSocket()
2. Initialize using FCGX_InitRequest()
3. Loop using FCGX_Accept_r() instead of FCGI_Accept()

Here is complete working example -

```
#include <fcgi_stdio.h>

#define PATH_SOCKET "/tmp/hello.sock"

int main() {
    int sock = FCGX_OpenSocket(PATH_SOCKET, 10);
    FCGX_Request request;

    FCGX_Init();
    FCGX_InitRequest(&request, sock, 0);

    while (FCGX_Accept_r(&request) == 0) {
        FCGX_FPrintF(request.out, "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n"
                "Hello World!\r\n");
        FCGX_Finish_r(&request);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unixman, nginx does not spawn FCGI services by itself. Your program needs to start and have a main loop which will accept FastCGI requests. Nginx will forward these requests to your software.

If you want an easy way of doing this (though the code is C++ and not C!) you can use either the [(F)CGI kit](http://cgi.sourceforge.net/) or the [Wt FCGI kit](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt). Both of these can/will handle the main loop for you, and then you just need to stick a call to your C code in the handler function.

Comment: I am not using a framework. I am using the FCGI API from fastcgi.com. All it says to do is call `FCGI_Accept` but that doesn't work. It just runs like a normal CGI and then exits.

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a unix domain socket listener and dup the socket descriptor to STDIN_FILENO.

```
dup2(socket, STDIN_FILENO);
while(FCGI_Accept() >= 0) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: @unixman83 Your application is the server and the webserver is the client, just decide where you want the unix domain socket and instruct your webserver (client) to connect to specified socket path. There is no need for further sockets, all messages is passed through the socket I said.

Comment: You are not showing STDOUT. How do I handle `STDOUT` and `STDERR`?